# itemId is changing after mail sent in outlook mail

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am getting `itemId` of a mail item after `saveAsync` in compose mode.

Once mail item is sent, item `Id` coming in `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId` is different than what is given in compose mode.

Code used for getting `itemId` in compose mode:

```js
var itemId = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
if (itemId === null || itemId == undefined) {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function (result) {
        itemId = result.value;
    });
}
```

After the email is sent, I verified email's `itemId` from sent box using:

```
`Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId`
```

to my surprise it is different.

According to the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.4/Office.context.mailbox.item?product=outlook&version=v1.4#nullable-itemid-string), the `itemId` should be the same:

> The `itemId` property is not available in compose mode. If an item identifier is required, the `saveAsync` method can be used to save the item to the store, which will return the item identifier in the `AsyncResult.value` parameter in the callback function.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First it is important to understand that an item's `itemId` is not a static value. The ID will change whenever an item is moved around in Exchange. From the [EWS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828(v=exchg.150).aspx#Distinguished%20folder%20IDs):

> Identifiers in Exchange are opaque. For example, the EwsId is created from several pieces of information that are not important to you as the developer, but are important to Exchange.

As to why this is happening, it is because `saveAsync` will result in the email being saved to the Drafts folder. When it is sent the item first moved to the Outbox and then into the Sent Items folder. Each of those folder changes (Drafts, Outbox, and Sent Items) results in a change to the `itemId` field.

Comment: So if I want to retrieve the email after it has been sent using the outlook rest api what do I need to do?

Comment: You could try the preview of [Immutable Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id), it might get around this issue.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping to stay within the available outlook rest api. Preview is a little too bleeding edge.