# ItemId not valid after email sent

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-restapi

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46076151/132599) answers part of my question - when I save an email I can retrieve its ItemId but as soon as it's sent the ItemId is invalid and a request to to the Outlook rest api to retrieve the email returns a 404.

My question then is how do I subsequently identify the email I just sent if the ItemId is different?

Answer (score 1):

You can stamp the message with your own custom property - it will be preserved when the message is moved to the Sent Items folder. You will be able to search on that property.

Comment: I'm not seeing that as an option on the api - any chance you could provide a little more detail?

Comment: Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/outlook/office.customproperties?view=outlook-js-preview

Comment: @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT . you suggest custom property approach. is itemId actually not valid after email sent as David Clarke said ?

Comment: Yes, ItemId changes when an item is moved to a different folder. Think of  it as a new item related to the original one.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT so I save a custom myId:Guid with a message. Once the message has been sent, how do I then retrieve it using my custom property? Can I just `me/messages?$search="myId:A8222FEC-2109-4D59-8B8C-A192E0E8E168"`?

Comment: Not quite as simple, but close: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-developer-exchange-docs/blob/master/docs/exchange-web-services/how-to-use-search-filters-with-ews-in-exchange.md

Comment: Refer: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4505745/cannot-save-meeting-as-draft-in-outlook-for-mac-using-office-js-api This link explains how to filter based on custom properties, might be helpful

Comment: Is there any way to get a stable identifier for an Outlook email item using the GUI/Web interface? or is there some sort of add-on I can use?

Comment: You can use OutlookSpy (click IMessage) to see any message properties (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy)