# Outlook: How to get from email-ID the "itemId" to use in office.js.api?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am developing add-in for outlook(web and desktop).For that I am using office.js.api for rest calls. One of the core functionalities of my add-in is reminder. User sends emails and add-in tracks that email id(it adds it to DB).
I want user to have option on pressing btn to open in new window needed email.

**What i know:**
To open emails in new window I need to use [displayMessageFormAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-mailbox-displaymessageformasync-member(1)) method from office.js.api.  But here is a problem as input it needs `ItemId` not `messageId`.

**So question is how to convert messageId to ItemId?**

Example of messageId:
`AQMkADAwATMwMAItNGIxMy0yYTAyLTAwAi0wMAoARgAAA5vuE8DX1vtBmAIURe25AdEHAENSlH9y8y9Jqcjhmi7n76AAAAIBDwAAAENSlH9y8y9Jqcjhmi7n76AAAAAGaAVeAAAA`
How it looks like in code

```
let tmp2='AQMkADAwATMwMAItNGIxMy0yYTAyLTAwAi0wMAoARgAAA5vuE8DX1vtBmAIURe25AdEHAENSlH9y8y9Jqcjhmi7n76AAAAIBDwAAAENSlH9y8y9Jqcjhmi7n76AAAAAGaAVeAAA'

Office.context.mailbox.displayMessageFormAsync(tmp2, function (asyncResult) {
                           console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult));
                          });
```

but if I pass as arg to method messageID it throws error in console
[image: error image]

Comment: Where does your messageid come from?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko from database. Record is from field `Office.context.mailbox.item.ItemId` what is added to record then user press Sent btn in Outlook.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I found source of bug. messageID in DB is different than using `Office.context.mailbox.item.ItemId`. Probably it changed when email status went from compose to sent.

Comment: Yes ItemId changes for an item when it is moved from one folder to another and it will not be constant on folder movement

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I assume you can not make it constant?

Comment: Yes it is like this by design ,follow this post for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46076151/itemid-is-changing-after-mail-sent-in-outlook-mail

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT okey understood what I need to use immutable identifiers. But can I use them in office.js or its only available in Graph API?

Comment: Immutable ids are Graph specific..Please go through this doc regarding immutable Ids https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So messageID are itemID but here is a trick. `ItemId changes for an item when it is moved from one folder to another and it will not be constant on folder movement` As suggested `Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT` need to use [immutable ids](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id) and somehow GRAPH API
`